# updating chrome cookies without opening the browser

Tags: google-chrome, autologin

As the subject says, I want to update chrome cookies without opening the browser, by using some script. This is done to do autologin into certain websites as soon as the user logins to the workstations. Can anyone help me in this regard.

I have script to retrieve the cookies from server, so this part of problem is solved.

Thanks and Best Regards,
                               - Rohin